# Chinese equivalent of "I'm stealing that joke"

Tags: translation

Is there a Chinese equivalent of I'm stealing that joke?

I just heard a hilarious joke, and I'd like to say "that's a great joke, I'm stealing it" (i.e. I will use it myself).

Is there a Chinese equivalent?

I suppose the idea of "stealing" a joke doesn't really fit into Chinese culture?

Comment: If not specifically for jokes, we say "拾人牙慧".

Comment: It's not the idea of stealing that doesn't fit into Chinese conversation, instead, making such statement is. If the intent is to applaud the joke or the joke teller, there are many other ways.

Answer (score 3):

Right, the word "stealing" doesn't fit into Chinese culture that much. We would use "borrow" instead, although we are not give it back anyway. The words in Chinese are "借用一下"，literally means borrow and use for a little bit. (We use a little bit at the end to soften the sentence and be more polite)

Answer (score 3):

"that's a great joke, I'm stealing it."

"好 段子 ，我 **抄** 去 用 了 哈～"

抄 = to copy, to transcribe, to plagiarize

Answer (score 3):

Chinese people not tend to say this during a conversation,(maybe because it's so nature to steal jokes, how many people invent jokes themselves?)

But we might say something similar during a text chat(SMS, onine chat,etc). user3685's is a good one. Or you may say "已转发(forwarded)","已收藏(added to my collection)"，"已右键(saved)",to show that you will use it later.

拾人牙慧(what was mentioned in the question's first comment) was definitely not what you are looking for, that's used for "borrowing other people's ideas **without referencing** "

Comment: If "I'm stealing that joke" shows their modesty or humility, 拾人牙慧 can be used in such a way.